# Multiple generic class based DetailView's for the SAME model

Tags: django, django-models, django-class-based-views

I am attempting to use two detail views that will render different templates for the same model, at different URLs of course.  Is it possible to have different generic detail views for the same model? If not I'll just have to write my own I suppose.  All my detail views route to the absoluteurl but in this case I want each detail view to route to the template I have defined in the class.

I used the method below to successfully create multiple list views and update views, but it just doesn't work on detail views, I always end up at "course_detail" even though I declared "course_detail_producer_view."

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Course"
        verbose_name_plural = "Courses"
        ordering = ['start_time']

    pub_partner_choices = [
        ("company1", "company1"),
        ('company2', 'company2'),
    ]
    status_choices = [
        ('hold', 'Hold'),
        ('editorial', 'Editorial'),
        ('approved', 'Approved'),
        ('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(max_length=100, help_text="course title",
                         populate_from=['title', 'date'], unique=True, )
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    new_course = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    new_instructor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    katacoda = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    jupyterhub = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    released = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                              choices=status_choices,
                              blank=False
                              )
    pub_partner = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                   choices=pub_partner_choices,
                                   blank=False)
    course_notes = models.TextField(max_length=500,
                                    blank=True,
                                    )
    producer_notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          editable=False
                          )
    producer = models.ManyToManyField(Producer,
                                      related_name="course",
                                      blank=True,
                                      )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Return URL to detail page of a Course"""
        return reverse(
            "course_detail",
            kwargs={"slug": self.slug}
        )

    def __str__(self):
        date_time = f"{self.date} {self.start_time}"
        return f"{self.title} : {date_time}"
```

urls.py

```
    path(
        'courses/<str:slug>/',
        CourseDetail.as_view(),
        name='course_detail'
        ),
    path(
        'courses/producer-view/<str:slug>/',
        CourseDetailProducerView.as_view(),
        name='course_detail_producer_view'
    ),
```

views.py

```
   class CourseDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
       queryset = Course.objects.all()
       template_name = 'lots_app/course_detail.html'


   class CourseDetailProducerView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
       queryset = Course.objects.all()
       template_name = 'lots_app/course_detail_producer_view.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was being caused by an UpdateView that was using reverse_lazy to get the absolute_url.  It turns out there was no problems with the DetailViews, just how I was trying to get to them (whoops!)  The solution was to override get_success_url().  The now corrected UpdateView looks like this:

```
class CourseUpdateProducerView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    form_class = CourseFormProducerView
    model = Course
    template_name = 'lots_app/course_form_producer_view.html'
    extra_context = {"update": True}

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        """Return the URL to redirect to after processing a valid form."""

        url = reverse_lazy('course_detail_producer_view',
                           kwargs={"slug": self.object.slug})

        return url
```